# Fullscreen doesn't work with clappr player

Tags: javascript, clappr

How to force Clappr player to stay fullscreen after change video?
I write a function that triggered on PLAYER_ENDED event, function loads next video with this `load` method:

```
enter code here`enter code here`player.load([{source: 'video_url_exmpl'}], null, true);
```

But when event was triggered and the new video loaded player cancels Fullscreen mode. I set up option:

```
exitFullscreenOnEnd: false,
```

I write a plugin that supposes to toggle fullscreen but browser throw a warning message:

```
Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture
```

Here is my Clappr player initialization and settings:

```
 player = new Clappr.Player({
        source: sourceUrl,
        parentId: "#player",
        autoPlay: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        exitFullscreenOnEnd: false,
        playInline: true,
        recycleVideo: Clappr.Browser.isMobile,
        poster: '',
    }).on(Clappr.Events.PLAYER_ENDED, function() {
           player.load([{source: 'video_url'}], null, true);
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the temporary solution on official Clappr GitHub Issues. Thanks to **kslimani**.

```
var player = new Clappr.Player({
  parentId: "#player-wrapper",
  source: 'http://clappr.io/highline.mp4',
  height: 360,
  width: 640,
  exitFullscreenOnEnd: false,
  playback: {
    playInline: true,
    recycleVideo: true,
  },
  events: {
    onEnded: function () {
      var setSource = function (newSrc) {
        this.core.options.source = newSrc;
        var container = this.core.getCurrentContainer();
        var playback = this.core.getCurrentPlayback();
        if (container) {
          container.options.source = newSrc;
        }
        if (playback) {
          playback.options.source = newSrc;
          playback._setupSrc && playback._setupSrc(newSrc);
        }
      }.bind(this);

      // Set another .mp4 source and start again player
      setSource('https://static.playmedia-cdn.net/resources/sample/h264_sintel_trailer-1080p.mp4');
      this.play();
    }
  }
});
```

Please note this code is an ugly trick which may let some player components (like plugins) in an inconsistent state. This work only if source are in same format (ie: all source are .mp4 files).
But should give you some hints to where to start to dig.
 [Link on Clappr GitHub threat](https://github.com/clappr/clappr/issues/1467)